Cryptography module not found
Im new to python, and I recently wanted to try and dive in into encrypting and decrypting text, so I looked up tutorials, and I see tutorials using the from cryptography.fernet import fernet. I did the same but it says module error, I did make sure it was downloaded. It is in the path miniconda/libs/site-packages. But it still says module error.(Also, I dont really know what miniconda is, my brother installed it for me)
Here is the code.
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
message = b"Secret message"
encrypted_message = cipher_suite.encrypt(message)
print("Key:", key)
print("Encrypted Message:", encrypted_message)
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
decrypted_message = cipher_suite.decrypt(encrypted_message)
print("Decrypted Message:", decrypted_message.decode())

I tried uninstalling cryptography module and reinstalling but has no effect

At this stage it's more important to see how you installed cryptography than it is to see your code. Show the commands you used and their output.

Well, I did pip install cryptography in the terminal, also did pip show cryptography to make sure it is there, which it is.
File "c:\Users\User\Downloads\Encypt.py", line 1, in 
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
The file exists in the path:
C:\Users\tonym\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages

Add to the top of your script: import os and print(sys.executable). What does it output? How are you running your script?

It does not say anything, Im not able to print(sys.executable), also I am running this in Visual Studio Code, I dont know if there is some way I need to do it so if you could, explain it like im 5 please.
`from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os
print(sys.executable)
Generate a key
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
`
